# html email signature not displaying inline css in gmail

Tags: android, html, css, email

So, for my email signature, I'm using custom html with inline css, as recommended for email usage.

This is what the signature is supposed to look like,

**red lines are just used to cover my personal details.**

[mail signature displayed normally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImCD1.png)

[mail signature without styling, both gmail android, gmail web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04RFf.png)

How do I get gmail to display my signature properly with css?

**EDIT:** Here is the code

```
<body style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); padding: 0; padding-top: 30px; margin: 0; letter-spacing: normal; orphans: auto; text-align: start; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; white-space: normal; widows: auto; word-spacing: 0px; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px; word-wrap: break-word; -webkit-nbsp-mode: space; -webkit-line-break: after-white-space;">

<style>
.signature {
    padding-top: 40px;
    font-weight: 100;
    word-break: all;
}

.vr {
    float: left;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    height: 138px;
}

.text-container {
    overflow: auto;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: black;
    padding-top: 0;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 28px;
}

h1 {
    margin-left: -2.5px;
    font-size: 34px;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: -6px;
    font-weight: 100;
}

.subtitle {
    font-size: 14px;
}

p {
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

.img {
    float: left;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin: -38px;
}

.contact-secondary {
    display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .signature {
        padding-left: 15px;
    }
    .img {
        float: none;
        width: 150px;
        margin-bottom: -20px;
        margin-top: -30px;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .text-container {
        padding-left: 0;
        margin-top: -10px;
        border: none;
    }
    .vr {
        display: none;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 350px) {
    .contact-secondary {
        display: inherit;
    }
    .contact-main {
        display: none;
    }
    .text-container {
        padding-left: 0;
        border: none;
        margin-top: -10px;
    }
    .vr {
        display: none;
    }
    .signature {
        padding-left: 15px;
    }
    .img {
        padding: 0;
    }
    .foot {
        font-size: 12px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 250px) {
    .img {
        float: none;
        width: 80px;
        margin: -20px;
        padding: 0;
    }
    h1 {
        font-size: 23px;
        padding-bottom: 4px;
        padding-left: 1px;
    }
    .subtitle {
        margin-top: -5px;
        margin-left: 0px;
        margin-bottom: -2px;
        font-size: 10px;
    }
    .signature {
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-top: 30px;
    }
    p {
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    .text-container {
        padding-left: 0;
        border: none;
        margin-top: 5px;
    }
    .contact-secondary {
        display: inherit;
    }
    .contact-main {
        display: none;
    }
    .vr {
        display: none;
    }
    .foot {
        font-size: 9px;
    }
}

</style>

<div class="signature"><img class="img" width="200px" src="http://harrypark.io/mail/logo.png" alt="harrypark.io logo">
<div class="vr"></div>
<div class="text-container">
    <h1><a href="http://harrypark.io/mail/vcard.vcf">Harry Park</a></h1>
    <p class="subtitle">Web Designer + Full Stack Developer</p>
    <div class="contact-main">
        <p><a href="http://harrypark.io">harrypark.io</a></p>
        <p><a href="mailto:MYEMAIL">MYEMAIL</a>&nbsp; |&nbsp;
            <a href="tel:MYPHONENUM">MYPHONENUM</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="contact-secondary">
        <p><a href="http://harrypark.io">harrypark.io</a></p>
        <p><a href="mailto:MYEMAIL">MYEMAIL</a></p>
        <p><a href="tel:MYPHONENUM">MYPHONENUM</a></p>
    </div>
    <p class="foot">web design&nbsp; |&nbsp; web development</p>
</div>
</div>

</body>
```

Sorry for the awkward formatting of code, stackoverflow makes it mighty hard.

Comment: so,,what is your question?

Comment: Sorry, completely forgot to add that bit!

Comment: can yo include your html and css code

Comment: Just added it, there's a fair bit of css, all the html is at the bottom

Comment: what if you remove all `@media` css?

Comment: Sadly, the same output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gmail doesn't support css inside `<style>` elements, you need to inline the css using style attributes. See: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

This tool might help you: https://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/inline-css/

Comment: So, then to have a responsive email signature, should I then include my base styles inline, and then responsive as a style tag?

Comment: Yup that's correct, so in `<style>` you will pretty much just have your media queries.